# Web Forms Response.RedirectToRoute and Ajax UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, click, updatepanel, redirecttoroute

I added a button in datalist in updatepanel (Web Forms/AJAX). Can we use Response.RedirectToRoute() in codebehind? I would like to send cat_id with it ofcourse if it's possible.

**I can use Response.Redirect in button click :**

```
protected void goto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Response.Redirect("Page.aspx?cat_id=3", true); // working
}
```

**I can't use Response.RedirectToRoute in button click:**

```
protected void goto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.RedirectToRoute("go", new { cat_id= 3 }); //not working
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "not working"?  What is it doing?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?  Are you routing to your own server or a public one?  If this is your own application, have you mapped your routes?  It seems like you're mixing web forms and MVC here...is that your intention?

Comment: @Ageonix  "not working" mean is button is not working. By the way it's my fault. I updated link, i hope that explains everything. As you know, there is global.asax i didn't add more code here. Just idea is simple. how to use redirecttoroute? in updatepanel. Why click event is not responsing.. is it from ajax? – All routes works out of updatepanel.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to be crazy.. i saw it's visual studio's problem. Response.RedirectToRoute(); is working in UpdatePanel. However, i coudn't understand why it didn't work (because it's same code) for a length of time.

Cheers